# How to add filters effects to Svg in d3

Tags: d3.js

```
<svg viewBox = "0 0 1100 400" version = "1.1">
    <desc>
        Filter example
    </desc>
    <filter id = "i1">
        <feGaussianBlur in = "SourceAlpha" stdDeviation = "4" result = "blur1"/>
        <feSpecularLighting result = "specOut" in = "blur1" specularExponent = "20" lighting-color = "#bbbbbb">
            <fePointLight x = "50" y = "100" z = "200"/>
        </feSpecularLighting>
        <feComposite in = "SourceGraphic" in2 = "specOut" operator = "arithmetic" k1 = "0" k2 = "1" k3 = "1" k4 = "0"/>
    </filter>
```

```
var svg=svg.selectAll(".circle")
      .data(this.Data)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "circle")
      .attr("r",function(d) {return r(Math.sqrt( d[2]));})
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
      .style("fill","blue");
```

how can I Add this filter to svg circle.

How can I use this filter effect in Svg(D3).
CanI use it directly or I have change to D3 format.

Comment: There's no D3 code in your question. You have a complete example there, it's not clear to me what you want to do with D3.

Comment: I have updated my question Can you please advise

Comment: You just need to add `.attr("filter", "url(#i1)")`.

Comment: I tried it but I am not able to see any svg circle.

Comment: You may need to adjust coordinates/offsets.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the `viewBox` attribute first from your first SVG, wrap it around an html and then with d3 you can add another svg tag containing your animation. Also you have to add to the circles you want the attribute `filter=url(#i1)` as told before.

I made a codepen to demonstrate how it works with [this d3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021841). [Take a look at it, works perfectly](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjmJbe).